# ASP.NET Web Api attribute routing and query string

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, query-string, attributerouting

I've specified my routing like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<User>))]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
    {

    }

    [Route("{birthdate}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<User>))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetByBirthdate(DateTime birthdate)
    {

    }
```

But when I am using this url: `localhost/Users?birthdate=1907-04-19&api-version=2.0`

I get redirected to GetAll() method. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
localhost/Users?birthdate=1907-04-19&api-version=2.0
```

that mean you call url users with param birthdate

If you want to go to second you need use

```
http://localhost/users/birthdate?birthdate=1907-04-19
```